# Quais métodos HTTP um crawler não pode rastrear?

Tags: http, web-crawler

Uma dúvida conceitual (ou não):

Dos métodos HTTP, quais deles não podem ser "rastreados" - ou interpretados - por um *crawler*?

- POST
- GET
- PUT
- PATCH
- DELETE

Alguém com conhecimento no assunto pode nos responder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela teoria, *crawlers* costumam executar métodos idempotentes e seguros - **OPTIONS, GET, HEAD**.

Do livro "**Cloud Standards: Agreements That Hold Together Clouds**":
"Web crawlers, for example, use only safe methods to avoid disturbing data on the sites they crawl"

Ou ainda:
"**Rastreadores da Web, por exemplo, utilizar apenas métodos seguros para evitar dados inquietantes sobre os sites que rastejam**"

O que faz todo o sentido para o **propósito** de um crawler, se pensarmos logicamente.

Uma ótima referência sobre o assunto é https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/http-methods/

> Idempotency and safety are important attributes of HTTP methods. An idempotent request can be called repeatedly with the same results as if it only had been executed once. If a user clicks a thumbnail of a cat picture and every click of the picture returns the same big cat picture, that HTTP request is idempotent. Non-idempotent requests can change each time they are called. So if a user clicks to post a comment, and each click produces a new comment, that is a non-idempotent request.
>
> Safe requests are requests that don’t alter a resource; non-safe requests have the ability to change a resource. For example, a user posting a comment is using a non-safe request, because the user is changing some resource on the web page; however, the user clicking the cat thumbnail is a safe request, because clicking the cat picture does not change the resource on the server.
>
> Production safe crawlers consider certain methods as always safe and idempotent, e.g. GET requests. Consequently, crawlers will send GET requests arbitrarily without worrying about the effect of repeated requests or that the request might change the resource. However, safe crawlers will recognize other methods, e.g. POST requests, as non-idempotent and unsafe. So, good web crawlers won’t send POST requests.

RFC sobre Safe e Idempotent Methods: http://w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

> 9.1.1 Safe Methods
>
> Implementors should be aware that the software represents the user in their interactions over the Internet, and should be careful to allow the user to be aware of any actions they might take which may have an unexpected significance to themselves or others.
>
> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe". This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.
>
> Naturally, it is not possible to ensure that the server does not generate side-effects as a result of performing a GET request; in fact, some dynamic resources consider that a feature. The important distinction here is that the user did not request the side-effects, so therefore cannot be held accountable for them.
>
> 9.1.2 Idempotent Methods
>
> Methods can also have the property of "idempotence" in that (aside from error or expiration issues) the side-effects of N > 0 identical requests is the same as for a single request. The methods GET, HEAD, PUT and DELETE share this property. Also, the methods OPTIONS and TRACE SHOULD NOT have side effects, and so are inherently idempotent.
>
> However, it is possible that a sequence of several requests is non- idempotent, even if all of the methods executed in that sequence are idempotent. (A sequence is idempotent if a single execution of the entire sequence always yields a result that is not changed by a reexecution of all, or part, of that sequence.) For example, a sequence is non-idempotent if its result depends on a value that is later modified in the same sequence.
>
> A sequence that never has side effects is idempotent, by definition (provided that no concurrent operations are being executed on the same set of resources).

Comment: Eu acho que se colocar mais um bloco embaixo traduzindo o termo em amarelo ajuda. Do jeito que está, não faz muito sentido no SOpt.

Comment: Infelizmente, apesar do stack ser em português, o mundo em que vivemos está repleto de conteúdo em inglês. Isso implica em, mesmo que não gostemos, aprender a conviver com o idioma.

Comment: Amigo, a questão é saber qual método http um crawler não pode rastrear...

Comment: Em programação sempre vamos nos deparar com inglês, uma tradução seria legal mas não acho obrigatório. seria interessante adicionar essa pergunta no META da nossa comunidade.

Comment: @MarllonNasser, O crawler pode rastrear qualquer Verbo http

Comment: @MarllonNasser os conceitos estão diretamente ligados.

Comment: Existe alguma "comprovação científica" disso? Alguma fonte -confiável- que mostre esse conceito?

Comment: O site é em português, logo, é natural que esperemos reposta em português. Você nao pode supor que TODO usuário que participe aqui, é obrigado a entender inglês. Eu mesmo não sei inglês e a resposta não me ajudaria se eu tivesse com um problema semelhante.

Comment: RFC sobre Safe e Idempotent Methods: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: @DiegoF
Essa discussão não está bem resolvida ainda.
http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/883/citando-conteudo-em-ingles/884#884

Comment: Sintam-se livres para traduzir o conteúdo, tal como expressões técnicas, crawler, put, get, options, head e também o RFC, se for o caso.

Comment: @MarllonNasser, Comprovação cientifica ?
acho que você não está entendendo o minimo do que está perguntando.
você pode testar o código e ler as referencias que foram passadas a você. não tem como ter comprovação cientifica se você não tem um ponto de falseabilidade

Comment: Daqui a pouco vcs vão estar tratando de Karl Popper kkk

Comment: "Web crawlers, for example, use only safe methods to avoid disturbing data on the sites they crawl" - Livro "Cloud Standards: Agreements That Hold Together Clouds"

Comment: @IsvaldoFernandes Não precisa traduzir "na integra" a citação inteira, mas fazer uma breve explicação(não precisa ser uma redação do ENEM também) sobre o que a citação diz, já torna a resposta muito mais completa. Entendo as dificuldades em se traduzir coisas técnicas, mas um resumo já ajuda quem lê a ter uma ideia.

Comment: @DiegoF Ideia resumida na edição da resposta

Comment: @IsvaldoFernandes a questão não é essa. Eu não tenho falseabilidade pois não tenho o conceito. E eu não posso me basear em: "Ah, funciona assim porque fulano de tal do SOPT falou", concorda? Mas ok... acho que fui convencido pelas respostas.

Answer (score 0):

Isso independe do Crawler, você pode simular qualquer request.

**Curl**

```
 curl --request POST 'http://www.somedomain.com/'
 curl --request DELETE 'http://www.somedomain.com/'
 curl --request PUT 'http://www.somedomain.com/'
```

fonte: [Link](http://www.yilmazhuseyin.com/blog/dev/curl-tutorial-examples-usage/)

**Python**

```
r = requests.put("http://httpbin.org/put")
>>> r = requests.delete("http://httpbin.org/delete")
>>> r = requests.head("http://httpbin.org/get")
>>> r = requests.options("http://httpbin.org/get")
```

fonte: [Link](http://engineering.hackerearth.com/2014/08/21/python-requests-module/)

**Java**

```
GetRequest request = Unirest.get(String url);
GetRequest request = Unirest.head(String url);
HttpRequestWithBody request = Unirest.post(String url);
HttpRequestWithBody request = Unirest.put(String url);
HttpRequestWithBody request = Unirest.patch(String url);
HttpRequestWithBody request = Unirest.options(String url);
HttpRequestWithBody request = Unirest.delete(String url);
```

Lib:[Link](http://unirest.io/java.html)

Comment: Amigo, a questão é saber qual método http (se existe) um crawler não pode rastrear...

Comment: @MarllonNasser, a resposta foi clara, não existe.